# Using endif for canceling dialog box not working

Tags: excel, vba

So my code works before I put in the end if, but once I try to implement the condition for if cancel is selected, I get a "else without if " compile error or something like that. I'm basically trying to do [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219843%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

This is the portion of my code that I'm talking about:

```
Public Function ChooseFolder()
'Declaring variables
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

'Folder selection
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing

    Else
    MsgBox ("You did not select any folders")
    End If

End With

End Function
```

Ok so the above has been fixed thanks to your help. What error I'm getting now (although it doesn't prevent the code from working is in this segment:

```
Private Sub btn_LeaveReport()
'Declaring variables
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim sFldr As String

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Added this bc of stack overflow advice. Basically how to reference path via string
sFldr = ChooseFolder()
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFldr)

'Hardcoded version commented out since the above choose folder option is available
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Administration\Time Sheets")
i = 3

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

For some reason the Set objFolder is creating a runtime error regarding an invalid procedure call. However, the program still works so I'm confused what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Public Function ChooseFolder()
    'Declaring variables
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    'Folder selection
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath

        If .Show = -1 Then
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
            ChooseFolder = sItem
        Else
            MsgBox ("You did not select any folders")
        End If
    End With

    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: that works but for some reason I still get a Run-time error for Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: apparently it's for a separate part of my code, basically after I select a folder (that whole part works now thanks to your help). So after that I have this (edit- nvm code is too long to put in comment will update above)

Answer (score 1):

The problemis the line

```
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
```

In VBA this is already a complete IF clause, so the later ELSE and End If are missing the starting IF clause.